# Type alias for immutable collections

Tags: scala, scala-collections

What is the best way to resolve the compilation error in the example below?  Assume that 'm' must be of type GenMap and I do not have control over the arguments of myFun.

```
import scala.collection.GenMap

object Test {
    def myFun(m: Map[Int, String]) = m

    val m: GenMap[Int, String] = Map(1 -> "One", 2 -> "two")


    //Build error here on m.seq
    // Found scala.collection.Map[Int, String]
    // Required scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int, String]
    val result = myFun(m.seq)
}
```

EDIT:

I should have been clearer. In my actual use-case I don't have control over myFun, so I have to pass it a Map. The 'm' also arises from another scala component as a GenMap. I need to convert one to another, but there appears to be a conflict between collection.Map and collection.immutable.Map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`m.seq.toMap` will solve your problem.

According to the signature presented in the [API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/milestone/index.html#scala.collection.Map) `toMap` returns a `scala.collection.immutable.Map` which is said to be required in your error message. `scala.collection.Map` returned by the `seq` method is a more general trait which besides being a parent to immutable map is also a parent to the mutable and concurrent map.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you offer any insight into why is wasn't working originally?

Comment: Sure. See the updates. You pretty much had the explanation in your question.

Comment: I didn't appreciate this 'parent' business before.  Has previously just assumed it was equivalent.  Clearly not.